# div height doesn't adjust when Accordion is collapsed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, chakra-ui

I have two charts on top of each other that extend to the bottom of the screen. The first is collapsible via an `Accordion`.

[image]

However, if I do the following two things in sequence:

1. Make my browser window bigger
2. Then, collapse the Accordion (i.e., minimize the first graph).

Then there will be unwanted whitespace below the second graph.

[image]
[image]

```
<Flex direction="column" height="calc(100vh)" className="flex-wrapper">
  <Box fontSize={["sm", "md", "lg", "xl"]}>Font Size</Box>
  <Flex className="flex-wrapper0">
    <div>123456789010</div>
    <Box className="accordion-box-container">
      <Accordion className="accordion-wrapper" allowToggle>
        <AccordionItem>
          <h2 className="accordion-title">
            <AccordionButton
              className="accordion-button"
              borderRadius="md"
              borderWidth="0px"
              _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
            >
              <Box
                textAlign="left"
                h={3}
                _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
              ></Box>
              <AccordionIcon />
            </AccordionButton>
          </h2>
          <AccordionPanel p="0">
            <Box height="30vh">
              <ThreeDataPoint />
            </Box>
          </AccordionPanel>
        </AccordionItem>
      </Accordion>
      <div className="graph-wrapper">
        <ThreeDataPoint />
      </div>
    </Box>
  </Flex>
</Flex>
```

It seems like some interaction problem between browser resizing and css? I think I need to force a re-rendering of `<ThreeDataPoint />` whenever the accordion button is pressed so that it can pick up the new height that it's supposed to be using. I wonder how to force such a re-rendering?

Here's codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fermat-bugv1?file=/src/index.tsx

And the app URL:

https://bugv1.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

It was because of this !important flag causing troubles in the css file:

```
.graph-wrapper div {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

After commenting this out, it worked as expected.